# Build dropdown in jqgrid from json string

Tags: json, jqgrid

In my edit form, I want to populate a drop down from the server.  I successfully return the values in a json string, to the client side:

```
var types = 
    $.ajax({
        url: getTypesUrl,
        async: false,
        success: function (data, result) {
            if (!result)
                alert("failed to retreive harvest types.");
        }
}).responseText;
```

returns this string:

```
 [{"HarvestTypeId":1,"TypeDescription":"Elite Gain / High Elev"},{"HarvestTypeId":2,"TypeDescription":"High Gain / High Elev"},{"HarvestTypeId":3,"TypeDescription":"Med Gain / High Elev"}]
```

I then add it to my jqgrid with the loadComplete:

```
$("#harvest-grid").jqGrid({
    url: gridUrl,
    styleUI: "Bootstrap",
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['HarvestId', 'Harvest Year', 'Harvest Type'],
    colModel: [
            { name: "HarvestId", key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: "HarvestYear", search: true, editable: true },
            { name: "HarvestType", search: true, editable: true, edittype: "select" }
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    height: "auto",
    autowidth: true,
    rowNum: -1,
    pager: "#harvest-pager",
    editurl: editHarvestUrl,
    loadComplete: function () {
        $("#harvest-grid").setColProp('HarvestType', { editoptions: { value: types } });
    }
});
```

The edit form shows a select list box, but renders the entire json string as the one and only option instead of building a list:

```
<select role="select" id="HarvestType" name="HarvestType" rowid="4430" size="1" class="FormElement form-control">
    <option role="option" value="[{&quot;HarvestTypeId&quot;">1,"TypeDescription":"Elite Gain / High Elev"},{"HarvestTypeId":2,"TypeDescription":"High Gain / High Elev"},{"HarvestTypeId":3,"TypeDescription":"Med Gain / High Elev"}]</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You use definitively wrong format of `editoptions.value` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions)). The usage of `async: false` is not good too. Why you don't use `dataUrl: getTypesUrl`? You can convert the data returned from `getTypesUrl` to `"<select><option value='1'>Elite Gain / High Elev</option><option value='2'>High Gain / High Elev</option><option value='3'>Med Gain / High Elev</option></select>"` inside of `buildSelect` callback.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I'll admit, I got lazy and didn't search the docs well enough.  That worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use *asynchronous* loading of the data using `dataUrl: getTypesUrl` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). You should specify additionally the `buildSelect` callback, which converts the data returned from `getTypesUrl` to the string

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>Elite Gain / High Elev</option>
    <option value='2'>High Gain / High Elev</option>
    <option value='3'>Med Gain / High Elev</option>
</select>
```

I'd recommend you additionally to add `prmNames: { id: "HarvestId" }` option and to remove the hidden column `"HarvestId"` in case if you use named properties (like `{"HarvestId": 123, "HarvestYear": 2016, "HarvestType": "Med Gain / High Elev"}`) in the data returned from `url: gridUrl`.